# How to insert new row at top of mat-table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table which displays a list of jobs.
Now when I create a new job I want to display it in first row rather than last one.If i create and add a new job it goes to bottom of mat-table.
How can I achieve this .

I want something similar to this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjzov-xc4kbp?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts).but rather than adding row at bottom i want it in first row

Comment: use ``.unshift(element)`` on your array

Comment: can you please explain in detail i am fairly new to angular

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To push an element to the first row , there is a method in array called `unshift()` .

To do that , take for an example :

`var a = [1,2,3,4];`
if i want to push `0` to `a` in the first position , i would simply do `a.unshift(0)`

All you have to do is instead of `.push()` , use `.unshift()`

I have forked the stackbltiz to help you out with the solution  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjzov-8zmcnp

Comment: Hi @CruelEngine using `.unshift()` I am able to insert a new row at the top of the table however on refreshing the page the inserted row shifts back to bottom of the page... how do I persist the row on top

Comment: @saad how are you fetching the data ? if the data is populated the way it is sent then you'll have to make the changes in the response of the api.

Comment: from api i am getting data and then I am displaying it on table

Comment: @saad make the changes in your api response to send the data to your requirements

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add new rows to the top of [MaterialTable](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props#options) you can add the fallowing option:

```
<MaterialTable
    ...
   options={
     addRowPosition: 'first'
   }
    ...    
>
```

You can only chose from *first* or *last*.  The default is set to *last*.

Answer (score 3):

With your datasource declared in your component as follows:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
```

You can add a rown to the top op the table with:

```
this.dataSource.data.unshift(newRowObject);
```